# google cloud billing API: update display name fail

Tags: google-apis-explorer, google-cloud-billing

I tried to use `billingAccounts.patch` with following details:

Request parameters:

`name= billingAccounts/01D70C-AEC6F8-675132`

Request body:

```json
{
  "displayName": "30_0201_81",
  "masterBillingAccount": "billingAccounts/012991-2189C9-1C4445"
}
```

but I received a response as follows:

`"message": "Request contains an invalid argument."`

Can anyone help me understand what the issue could be?

Comment: I doubt it matters but remove the spaces after the :